# How to add custom fields to pivot view using custom model in Odoo 9.0

Tags: python, odoo, pivot-table, odoo-9

I spent plenty of hours searching and trying to add custom field to pivot view in Odoo 9.0 point of sale report. I have no idea what I must to write in my custom module to add new field(specifically payment method) into pivot.

Thank you for help and have a nice day ;)

edit:

Here you have what I want to do, I want to add field payment method to these other:

[image]

Comment: For which view, you are trying to add the field. Can you share your code, what you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

Forgive me if its too late for the answer.

I think the best way is to override the pivot view by adding you new field in your own module. When you install your module, the default view will be overriden with your customized version. Here is an example how I did it for Timesheets module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="timesheets_pivot_extension">
            <field name="name">timesheets.pivot</field>
            <field name="model">account.analytic.line</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_timesheet.view_hr_timesheet_line_pivot"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <pivot>
                    <field name="my_custom_field" type="measure" />
                </pivot>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Here, ofc, "my_custom_field" is my own field, which I added to the account.analytic.line model (Timesheets). 
This is also easy:

```
class AccountAnalyticLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.analytic.line'

    my_custom_field = fields.Float(store=True, readonly=True)
```

And that's it. I populate this custom field with my own values at some point using ORM layer from Odoo.

Hope it helps, best of luck!

Regards,
Boris

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever checked under the Odoo Addons Folders, for example in you problem, please check `Odoo/addons/point_of_sale/report/`
there is `pos_report.py` and `pos_order_report_view.xml`

1. You can add your custom fields inside

   ```
   _columns = {
      .....
   }
   ```
2. Add your custom query inside it.

   ```
   def init(self, cr):
      tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, 'report_transaction_pos')
      cr.execute("""
          .........
      """""")
   ```
3. Add your custom view in `pos_order_report_view.xml`
   3.1 Create your own record or just use view inheritance.

Comment: It's perfect answer for me to add new field at pivot view of POS Sales Analysis. :) Thanks!